# TestNG error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, testng

Getting attribute `parallel` with value `none` must have a value from the list "false methods tests class" error on my XML in Eclipse. I am stuck because of this error.

Please help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite Name" parallel="none">
```

I did try changing value of `parallel` to "false", however issue still occurs.
Changed code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite Name" parallel="false">
```

Comment: Just remove that parallel = none

Comment: Or try false Instead of none

Answer (score 1):

See this, i dont have any issue

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
 <suite name="Suite" preserve-order="true" parallel="false">
   <test name="Test1">
    <classes>
     <class name="com.test.Test1"/>
     <class name="com.test.Test2"/>
   </classes>
 </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Just try by delete and typing again or you can use ctrl+space by typing few chars

Thank You,
Murali

Answer (score 1):

Try with https, replacing "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" with "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd"